# Rails 3: simple_format not printing "< xx >"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I want to print text to HTML. I'm using simple_format, however everything seems to be right except that what is inside "< >" is not printed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in a `:sanitize` option to tell it not to sanitize your tags:

```
<%= simple_text(my_string, nil, :sanitize => false) %>
```